# expressJs multiple callbacks manipulating the same data object

Tags: node.js, express, promise, bluebird

I have a scenario where I need to make multiple calls in the series like below.
I am updating the main data object that gets returned by 'loadBaseData' function, and then need to call 'grindCoffee' function again to make additional modifications of the same data object.

But the data don't resist, by the time in processResponse, all the options were empty.

```
app.post('/makecoffee', loadBaseData, grindCoffee, addWater, brewCoffee, processResponse);

        function loadBaseData (req, res, next) {
          pgServer.dbSelectData(req.body.username)
            .then(function(data) { 
              req.data = data;
              next();
            })
            .catch(function(err) { 
              res.send({success:false,message:'error, '+ err}); 
            });  
        }

            function grindCoffee (req,res,next){
              var records = req.data;

              for (j = 0; j< records.length; j++) { 
                if (Condition A){
                  dsServer.grindCoffee(function(res){          
                      if (Condition B){
                        req.data[i].options = res;
                        next();
                      }                    
                  });            
                }
              }
              next();
            }  
        // addWater and brewCoffee are similar to grindCoffee, it keeps updating the req.data

            function processResponse(req,res){
              res.send({success:true,data:req.data});
            }
```

**Edit:**
I think maybe use promise like bluebird may help with this situation, but I am not sure how to convert this to it.

Comment: Don't call `next()` from within a loop?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, using bluebird promise is really elegant and simple, this solved the problem:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");

//all sub tasks such as grindCoffee, addWater, and brewCoffee need to be turn into promises like this

function grindCoffeeAsync (){
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    dsServer.grindCoffee(function(data){
      resolve(data);
    });
  });
}

  Promise.all([
      pgServer. dbSelectData(username),
      grindCoffeeAsync(),
      addWaterAsync(),
      brewCoffeeAsync()
    ])
    .spread(function(p1,p2, p3, p4){
      //p1 is the result from the first promise
      //p2 is the result from the second promise.....
      //you can manipulate all 4 results here
      var allObjects = [];
      allObjects.push(p1);
      allObjects.push(p1);
      allObjects.push(p1);
      allObjects.push(p1);

      return allObjects;
}).then(function(result){
   console.log(result); //you will get all 4 results from allObjects
})
```